# Salesforce - Validation rule to insert character at specific position

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to write a validation rule for a specific business case where we have to insert a 'space' at the '6th' character position in a certain field.

For e.g., if the user enters "ABCDEFGHIJKL" in the field, I should save it as "ABCDEF GHIJKL" (space after 6th character 'F') when the user saves the record.

I did look at LPAD and RPAD, but I am not sure how I can use these.
Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a validation rule can't actually insert characters or otherwise change any data; it can only throw an error if a user hasn't entered the data properly.

If that is sufficient for you (to just throw an error) then you can make a validation rule with a formula like

```
MID(Field__c,6,1)<>" "
```

And that will throw an error if there's not a space there.  If you want to *insert* a space you can do it with a similar formula in a workflow rule.  So make a workflow rule with the same formula as its criteria:

```
MID(Field__c,6,1)<>" "
```

And then make a field update on it that updates that same field to

```
MID(Field__c,1,6)&" "&MID(Field__c,7,LEN(Field__c)-7)
```

Take these formulas with a grain of salt as I just came up with them off the top of my head and didn't actually compile them, but they're probably either very close or spot on.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @amrcn_werewolf. It appears that LEFT takes only 2 parameters. So, I took your suggestion to throw an error with this rule:`LEN ( Field__c) > 5,
FIND(" ", Field__c, 5)<>6`

Comment: Hence my disclaimer about the formula, I was treating LEFT and RIGHT like MID.  So what you really wanted there is MID(Field__c,6,1) -- I'm going to edit it accordingly so as not to mislead future readers.